# Is there a time-line graphic for A Song of Ice and Fire?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Is there a chart for A Song of Ice and Fire that is similar to [these charts](http://xkcd.com/657/large/) for Lord of the Rings and Star Wars that were made by Randall Munroe?

It would really help to keep track of the whereabouts of all characters in such a complicated series.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[This site](http://www.sermountaingoat.co.uk/) is what you want. It hosts this monstrosity of a chart (1.6 MB png file):

[sermountaingoat.co.uk: Timeline - Narrative Chart (PNG)](http://www.sermountaingoat.co.uk/timeline/info/narrative_chart.png)

It only covers events up to the fourth book, and the site itself has other resources, including a unique animated time line map.

Comment: Great stuff! It's almost exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: made a minor edit to the link, feel free to roll it back.